Could not resolve main entrypoint function when using flutter_background_service
i am developing an application that will hit an api containing user position from geolocator in background using flutter_background_service but sometimes this error occur and the service wont work.

This is my onStart in main.dart
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
    service.on("stop").listen((event) {
    service.stopSelf();
  });

  service.on("start").listen((event) {});

  Timer.periodic(const Duration(minutes: 15), (timer) async {
    final currentLocation = await Geolocator.getLastKnownPosition(
      forceAndroidLocationManager: true);

    final id = await CommonUtils.readFromSecureStorage(
        key: CommonConstants.attendanceId);

    await DioClient().post(endpoint: url, body: requestBody);
  });
}

